# Is there an easy way to create fonts that use alternate Unicode glyphs

Tags: unicode, fonts, truetype, glyph-substitution

I would like to create a new font that has alternate Unicode glyphs for the letters to create secret codes for my nieces and nephews.  So for example, I would be able to write them a letter in plain text (ABC), highlight the text and switch it to my custom font, so that “hello world” would turn into something like “פछ௶௶Ꮂ ᜋᎲ᯼௶ⵥ”.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Creating fonts is a different craft than programming. So your Question is not appropriate to this site. I suggest trying a sibling site such as http://www.SuperUser.com/, or a forum site. There are apps for editing fonts, and you could start with an open-source font to edit rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about crafting fonts, not about programming.